# how to test for value in array and extract value

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the **var_dumped** value from an uploaded photo. I need to test whether the **Id key** has a value and then extract that value.

I looked up array_values() but this does not first test whether the Id has a value and then extract the value of the Id key.

```
array (size=3)
  'Id' => string 'photo' (length=9)
  'submit' => string 'Upload Now' (length=10)
  'fileupload' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'New-smaller-Coca-Cola-can-001.jpg' (length=33)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php4030.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 21841
  '
```

Comment: $arr = ['Id' => 'Test']; $result = !empty($arr['Id']); 
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) ?

```
echo !array_key_exists('Id',$array)?'N/A':$array['Id']; //"prints" photo
```

Comment: hi shankar. but i want to extract the value from teh array Id. i mean, i first wish to test that the key has a value and then extract that value

Comment: May i know your expected output actually ?